# Can't create Drill storage plugin for oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-drill, apache-zookeeper

I want to create storage plugin in drill for oracle jdbc. I copy `ojdbc7.jar` to `apache-drill-1.3.0/jars/3rdparty` path and add `drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "/mypath"` to `dill.override.conf`.
when I want to create a new storage plugin with below configuration:

```
 {
  "type": "jdbc",
  "enabled": true,
  "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
  "url":"jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@x.x.x.x:1521/orcll"
}
```

I get **unable to create/update storage** error.

I am using Redhat 7 & Drill version - 1.3. in distributed mode.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with default schema name. It should be **orcl** instead of **orcll**.

Plugin:

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "enabled": true
  "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
  "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@x.x.x.x:1521:orcl"   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is with `"type" : "jdbc"` , my schema name is **orcll** __not__ **orcl** and if I change schema name the problem remains.

Comment: @ZahraSafavifar what is the problem with `"type" : "jdbc"` ?